# Switching language with href

Tags: php, html, url

I have three languages running on my website and would like to have working buttons to switch languages on the bottom of my page. The problem is, that the homepage (index.php) requires the suffix `?lang=X` while the other pages, (index.php?contact, index.php?about etc) require `&lang=X` in the URL.

I've set up my a href's like this:

```
<?php if((isSet($_GET['about']) == true && empty($_GET['about']) == true) || (isSet($_GET['contact']) == true && empty($_GET['contact']) == true)) { ?>
        <a href="&lang=en"><img src="img/en.gif" alt="English" /> English</a> | <a href="&lang=fr"><img src="img/fr.gif" alt="fran&ccedil;ais" /> fran&ccedil;ais</a> | <a href="&lang=nl"><img src="img/nl.gif" alt="Nederlands" /> Nederlands</a></p>
<?php } else { ?>   
        <a href="?lang=en"><img src="img/en.gif" alt="English" /> English</a> | <a href="?lang=fr"><img src="img/fr.gif" alt="fran&ccedil;ais" /> fran&ccedil;ais</a> | <a href="?lang=nl"><img src="img/nl.gif" alt="Nederlands" /> Nederlands</a></p>
<?php } ?>
```

It fixes the problem with the '?' or '&', but whenever I click the language change button on a page other than the homepage, it takes me to the homepage instead of staying on the current page, though the language switch does work. I suppose this is caused by my .htaccess file which rewrites the homepage to void and the contact and about pages to '/contact' and '/about'.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this? Or on how this language switching can be done much more easily?

Comment: I prefer using the cooking, i.e., when you click the language option i will set the cookie in browser. It won't be changed unless the user changes the pages, So i will get clean url too. You want me to help in this ?

Comment: It does store the chosen language as a cookie for 30 days, how can I do this with an `<a href=""` then?

Comment: So the actual language switching is not a problem, once a language is chosen it will remain that way for 30 days or until another language is chosen. It is the url to switch language that is malfunctioning.

Comment: Ah, You invoke only from `$_GET` Why not you do by `If Cookie Exists` ?

Comment: The `$_GET`s in my code above are for pagination, not the language setting. But I suppose I could use javascript to make the `href` set a cookie upon being clicked?

Comment: You can do [this](https://eval.in/379093) but do you ?

Comment: I though of recommending the best way, but if you just needs to fix the navigation problem i can help you. Do you ?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to just fix the navigation problem for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the OP Just needs to fix the **Navigation problem**. Here's what i would do.

I would just take the current page url by

```
$Url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

and then concat with the navigation

```
<a href="<?php echo $Url ?>?lang=en">Home</a>
```

So, The Code will be

```
<?php
$Url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
?>
<a href="<?php echo $Url ?>?lang=en">Home</a>
```

**Note :**

I am using `en` as static you can change it dynamically according to your need.

Comment: This code stops the link entirely from working. Because of my .htaccess file, the page 'contact' for example is changed from `/index.php?contact` to `/contact`. So when appending `?lang=X` to the URL, it does not work. It requires an '&' on all pages other than the homepage itself.

Comment: You mean, you can `&` too in your url ?

Comment: The URL is appearing correctly, but nothing happens when I attempt to click it.

Comment: You mean something like this `/index.php?contact&lang=en` ?

Comment: Yes, I changed it so that an & is added, and the url shows `localhost/contact&lang=en` but I cannot click it for some reason. When copying the link and pasting it into the url bar it does work.

Comment: Is the `<a href` tag properly formed ? Can you see it in page source ?

Comment: Yes, the source code shows: `<a href="localhost:8080/contact&lang=en">` just like it's supposed to, but nothing happens when it is clicked.

Comment: I believe `<a href="localhost:8080/about&lang=en">About</a>` is the url generated. Isn't it ?

Comment: You got any error in console or error log ?  Because the url is generated succesfully !!

Comment: Was in travel, Shall assist you in few time, Can you try to fix the problem. Because i can't able to see what happens there .. (I though only url generation is your issue :) )

Comment: Yes, for some reason the url is not working when clicked, but it does work when copied & pasted. I think I'll just go for javascript and have the links set a cookie when clicked :P Thanks a lot for your help though :)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the params in the current URL and append the new one into it, like so:

```
$params = array_merge($_GET, array("lang" => "X"));
$new_query_string = http_build_query($params);
```

But using a cookie will help not "loose" the language param when moving from one page to another. And leave a cleaner URL

**with cookies:**

at the top of your website pages

```
if ($_GET['lang'])
{
    setcookie("lang", $_GET['lang'], time() + 3600);
}
```

and in your language panel set:

```
<a href="?lang=X" title="X language">X</a>
<a href="?lang=Y" title="Y language">Y</a>
<a href="?lang=Z" title="Z language">Z</a>
```

Comment: When a language is set, it will store a cookie for 30 days. So if you can find a way to make the `href` set a cookie instead of appending to the URL, that would be much appreciated

Comment: If this is the answer you were looking for please mark the answer as solved